# Kibana, how can I ignore query strings?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have configured a Kibana using AWS infrastructure. I'm using AWS CloudWatch Logs and AWS ElasticSearch which contains Kibana software. As you can imagine, I'm uploading all my logs to Kibana. 
I'm trying to obtain a list of the most traffic URL's omitting query strings... but I don't know if this is possible.

Can you help me? I've search it on Google and on Elastic documentation, but I didn't found anything.

Here is an example:

Suppose that I have the following URL's:

- abc.com/helloWorld.html?param=1
- abc.com/helloWorld.html?param=2
- abc.com/helloWorld.html?param=3
- abc.com/bye.html?anotherParam=1

I want to see the following URL's in order to compute the sum of requests per file. Is it possible?

- abc.com/helloWorld.html
- abc.com/helloWorld.html
- abc.com/helloWorld.html
- abc.com/bye.html

Thanks,

Comment: Does your fields are analyzed?

Comment: why don't you just filter out the queryString, and create a field for the url using grok? you can then index the url field and use it

Comment: Thanks Arad, I will investigate it :)